# How to filter objects by string comparison in Swift

Tags: swift, string

I'm having an array of models:

```
struct Contact {
    var givenName: String!
    var familyName: String!
    var organizationName: String!
}
```

I want to filter those contacts using ONE `UITextField`. My current problem is to define between words and filter only contacts matching all words.

For example:

```
var contacts: [Contact] = [Contact(givenName: "David", familyName: "Seek", organizationName: "Aldi"),
                           Contact(givenName: "Johne", familyName: "Doe", organizationName: "Kaisers"),
                           Contact(givenName: "Jane", familyName: "Doe", organizationName: "Tengelmann"),
                           Contact(givenName: "Marco", familyName: "Seidl", organizationName: "Rewe"),
                           Contact(givenName: "Filip", familyName: "Halbig", organizationName: "Aldi")]
```

I want to enter: `David Aldi` and only find David who works at Aldi. I don't want to see Filip who also works at Aldi.

Also if I enter `David Do`, I don't want to see any contacts, because none should match.

```
func getSearchResults(_ filterKey: String) {
        self.presentActivityIndicator()
        var processed: Int = 0
        self.filteredContacts.removeAll()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            for contact in self.unfilteredContacts {
                processed += 1
                let lowercasedGivenName = contact.givenName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").lowercased()
                let lowercasedFamilyName = contact.familyName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").lowercased()
                let lowercasedOrganizationName = contact.organizationName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").lowercased()

                let name = lowercasedGivenName.appending(lowercasedFamilyName)

                if name.range(of: filterKey.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")) != nil {
                    if !self.filteredContacts.contains(contact) {
                        self.filteredContacts.append(contact)
                    }
                }

                for word in filterKey.components(separatedBy: " ") {
                    if lowercasedOrganizationName.range(of: word.lowercased()) != nil {
                        if !self.filteredContacts.contains(contact) {
                            self.filteredContacts.append(contact)
                        }
                    }
                }

                if processed == self.unfilteredContacts.count {
                    self.reloadTableViewInMainThread()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is one of the several approaches I've tried today. But with every try, I've been ending up, filtering out David and by entering the second name, I have found other contacts not matching the first name David, but match for example part of the family name or company name.

What am I missing and would be the best approach for this? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: A struct whose members are all mutable implicitly unwrapped optionals... That's concerning.

Comment: @Alexander it's not my final code. in the final code it's an array of CNContacts. it's just an example from playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func getSearchResults(contacts: [Contact], filterKeys: String) -> [Contact] {
    let keys = filterKeys.components(separatedBy: " ")
    var contactsFiltered = contacts

    keys.forEach { key in
        contactsFiltered = contactsFiltered.filter {
            $0.givenName == key || $0.familyName == key || $0.organizationName == key
        }
    }

    return contactsFiltered
}
```

I splitted the `filterKeys` by blank spaces. Then, for each key, I check if the value exists in contact attribute.

If do you want a pure functional solution, you can use `Set` and `intersection`:

```
func getSearchResults(contacts: [Contact], filterKeys: String) -> [Contact] {
    let keys = filterKeys.components(separatedBy: " ")

    return contacts.filter {
        Set([$0.givenName, $0.familyName, $0.organizationName]).intersection(keys).count >= keys.count
    }
}
```

And, if do you want a crazy solution with `Mirror`, for when adding a new attribute in `Contact`, you do not need to update `getSearchResults`:

```
func getSearchResults(contacts: [Contact], filterKeys: String) -> [Contact] {
    let keys = filterKeys.components(separatedBy: " ")

    return contacts.filter {
        let stringAttr = Mirror(reflecting: $0).children.filter { ($0.value as? String) != nil }
        let contactValues = stringAttr.map { $0.value as! String }

        return Set(contactValues).intersection(keys).count >= keys.count
    }
}
```

Use with caution my last code (or never use it)

**Edit**

For match part of string in key.

```
func getSearchResults(contacts: [Contact], filterKeys: String) -> [Contact] {
    let keys = filterKeys.components(separatedBy: " ").map { $0.lowercased() }
    var contactsFiltered = contacts

    keys.forEach { key in
        contactsFiltered = contactsFiltered.filter {
            $0.givenName.lowercased().range(of: key) != nil ||
            $0.familyName.lowercased().range(of: key) != nil ||
            $0.organizationName.lowercased().range(of: key) != nil
        }
    }

    return contactsFiltered
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. will check it out in a minute

Comment: problem with me for your solution is, that it only returns the contact, if the key is EXACT. like David == David. but I want David to be returned, even if I only enter Dav or Da or Davi, you know?

Comment: @DavidSeek Well... you didn't say it in the question... anyway, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

First separate the `filterKey` into space separated components

```
let components = filterKey.components(separatedBy: " ")
```

then use the `filter` function with the closure syntax

```
self.filteredContacts = contacts.filter { contact -> Bool in
    for string in components {
        if contact.givenName != string && contact.familyName != string && contact.organizationName != string {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

The closure returns `true` if the contact matches all components.

---

Wrapped in the function it's

```
func getSearchResults(_ filterKey: String) {

    let components = filterKey.components(separatedBy: " ")

    self.filteredContacts = contacts.filter { contact -> Bool in
        for string in components {
            if contact.givenName != string && contact.familyName != string && contact.organizationName != string {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

---

Note:

Please, please **never** declare properties / members as implicit unwrapped optionals which are initialized with an `init` method. It perfectly legal (and recommended) to declare the members without the exclamation marks. However if they are supposed to be optional declare them as real optional (question mark).

And if the values won't change declare the members as constants (`let`).

```
struct Contact {
    let givenName: String
    let familyName: String
    let organizationName: String
}
```

---

**Edit:**

To filter the contacts whose properties **contain** `filterKey` write

```
self.filteredContacts  = contacts.filter { contact -> Bool in
    for string in components {
        if !contact.givenName.lowercased().contains(string) &&
            !contact.familyName.lowercased().contains(string) &&
            !contact.organizationName.lowercased().contains(string) {
                return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

To filter the contacts whose properties **begin with** `filterKey` write

```
self.filteredContacts = contacts.filter { contact -> Bool in
    for string in components {
        if !contact.givenName.lowercased().hasPrefix(string) &&
            !contact.familyName.lowercased().hasPrefix(string) &&
            !contact.organizationName.lowercased().hasPrefix(string) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Why is recommended never declare the members without exclamation marks?

Comment: @Macabeus Implicit unwrapped optionals are often suggested as a convenient way (I call it **alibi**) not to write initializers. That's a very bad habit. Any (carelessly) implicit unwrapped optional will crash the app immediately if it has no value. A property / member initialized in an `init` method is supposed to be optional (`?`) or non-optional, nothing else. In case of a struct IUO are nonsense anyway because you get the memberwise initializer for free.

Comment: thank you for the side note on the optionals. but as stated in the comment of my question, it was just an example model from the playground. in the real version, those are CNContact objects. thank you for your help, will check it out in a minute

Comment: same here: problem with me for your solution is, that it only returns the contact, if the key is EXACT. like David == David. but I want David to be returned, even if I only enter Dav or Da or Davi, you know?

Comment: Your question is not clear whether a property is supposed to **match**, **contain** or **begin with** the query. I edited the answer.