# Filtering objects by multiple keywords in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, filter, range

I am trying to filter objects based on multiple keys (name, surname, job title, employee ID) in random order.
For example for employee (John, Newman, Accountant, 1234) I want to find him based on this searches:

- John 1234
- Newman Accountant
  etc.

I have found a great solution in a similar question ->  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725182/how-to-filter-objects-by-string-comparison-in-swift#) but I could not comment on it because of low reputation.

```
func getSearchResults(_ filterKey: String) {

    let components = filterKey.components(separatedBy: " ")

    self.filteredContacts = contacts.filter { contact -> Bool in
        for string in components {
            if contact.givenName != string && contact.familyName != string && contact.organizationName != string {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

I modified the code in this way:

```
func getSearchResults(_ filterKey: String) {

    let components = filterKey.components(separatedBy: " ")

    self.filteredContacts = contacts.filter { contact -> Bool in
        for string in components {
            if !(contact.givenName.range(of: string, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil) && contact.familyName.range(of: string, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil) && contact.organizationName.range(of: string, options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) != nil) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

It works very well apart from one detail - as soon as I hit space after first word, search results are empty and just when I start typing the second word results are back as expected.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I would like to see the search results for "John" even when the current search term is "John "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cut leading and trailing whitespace characters before splitting the string

```
let components = filterKey.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).components(separatedBy: " ")
```

or modify the loop

```
for string in components where !string.isEmpty { ...
```